# Word that means "relating to spiders"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is a word that means "relating to spiders" in the same way that *arboreal* means "relating with trees"?

My first instinct would have been something like *arachnean* but apparently that's not a word.

Comment: The word is "arachnidan".

Comment: @Graffito I thought that that was a noun, singular Arachnida.

Comment: @theonlygusti: "Arachnidan" can be a noun or an adjective. When used as a noun, it has the regular plural form "arachnidans." "Arachnida" is a separate word that is the name of of a taxonomic class, and therefore is only used in one grammatical number in English. (I don't know whether it is singular or plural in Latin.)

Comment: Please note that the preposition you should have used is "to" not "with". "With" would imply talking to them or being sympathetic towards them, which I don't think is what you intended. I've changed it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adjective: **arachnoid**  u'rak,noyd

(zoology) relating to or resembling a member of the class Arachnida

- arachnidian, spidery, spiderlike, spiderly

  -- [WordWebOnLine](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=arachnoid)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been able to find a fully satisfactory word meaning "relating to spiders" that is in common use. [Drew's suggestion of *arachnoid*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/377436/77227) and [Graffito's suggestion of *arachnidan*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/377435/word-that-means-relating-with-spiders/377454#comment885581_377435) are probably the two best options, if you must use an adjective. (In attributive position, it's often possible to use a noun in English, e.g. we can just say "spider habits" to mean "habits related to spiders.")

It sounds like you are looking for a word derived from Latin or Greek. I used Wiktionary to check the words in these languages for "[spider](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spider#Translations)." It says they are "aranea/araneus" and "arachne" respectively.

Then I used [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com) to look for words starting with *arane-* and *arachn-.* Here are some candidates that I found:

- *araneal* has apparently been used by someone at some point, but it is extremely rare. Only one of the dictionaries indexed by OneLook gives a definition: [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/araneal) ("Pertaining to or resembling the spider.") It's not listed in the Oxford English Dictionary, it doesn't show up on the [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=araneal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=), and I can't find any indication that the hypothetical Latin ancestor "aranealis" was ever used (although there is some species named *Mesochorus aranealis*). So even though it is the word I found that is most similar in formation to *arboreal,* I would be cautious about using it. However, one advantage to using a word like this that is almost never used is that it hasn't developed other conflicting specialized meanings, like the following words.
- *[araneous](http://www.onelook.com/?w=araneous&ls=a)* also exists. However, it seems to have a specialized meaning of "resembling or full of spiderwebs" (it seems "spiderweb" was another meaning of Latin *aranea*). So it might not be a good choice for you. A variant form is *araneose.*
- *[arachnoid](http://www.onelook.com/?w=arachnoid&ls=a),* oddly enough, has the same specialized meaning as *araneous.* It often refers to fibrous materials that are like spiderwebs, rather than things that resemble or pertain to spiders themselves. But it can have the latter meaning. My sense is the the *-oid* suffix sounds more natural when used to mean "resembling" rather than "pertaining to," which biases me against using this word to mean "pertaining to spiders."

Wiktionary itself has an [Appendix:Animals](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Animals#S) that suggests that *arachnidan* and *araneidan* are the adjectives corresponding to "*spider.* However, there are minor issues with each of these.

- *Arachnidan* may refer to a larger class than "spiders." It is derived from the word *[arachnid](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arachnid),* and may be applied to any animal of this type, which includes scorpions, ticks and mites in addition to spiders. The variants *arachnidean, arachnidian* would have the same problem.
- *Araneidan* usually refers to a subset of the spiders: the *[araneids](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/araneidan),* spiders that belong to the orb weaver family. The variant *araneidal* would have the same problem.

There are also a few possibilities for adjectives derived from the English word *spider.* *Spidery* is relatively common (compared to any of the Latinate words), and generally has the sense "resembling a spider", although in some cases it seems closer in meaning to "resembling a spiderweb". *Spiderish* is less common than *spidery,* but to me it seems that *spiderish* has a somewhat vaguer meaning. *Spiderlike* is an adjective that more explicitly conveys "resembling a spider (or part of a spider)". *Spiderly* seems to be more or less a synonym of *spidery.*

Answer (score -3):

Without exposing to much ignorance, I feel saying "Arachniphile" would be a justifiable construction and a generally translatable insertion into conversation. 
"Philia"(Arachnaphile) being a strong tendency toward and "Phobia"(Arachnaphobic) being an aversion to, they appear to be suffixes in opposition.

Comment: "-phile" does not mean "relating to". As you say in your answer, it means "strong tendency towards". This therefore is a very poor answer.

Comment: *Arachniphile* sounds like somebody who loves spiders.

Comment: @Andy It seems you simply wish to impose your will.  Language is malleable and develops with interpretation. I for one, though not an English major, would not want to sit in on a lecture of yours.  Reread your denoted material and I'm sure you'll find more than your single bit "strong tendency toward", hangin' you on your own Petard.

Comment: @Andy, You might also want to correct your spelling as the five letters "phile", you built into your spirited assault cannot be found in any modern Western dictionary, available on my Google page.

Comment: @ Andy, I must apologize, but I twice attempted to start a new paragraph and the enter tab sent, the above excerpts, into play.  I was hoping for a single long winded snap at your correction and instead got these parsed elements.  As an aside, I admit to not reading the query as the author had intended, but that in no way relieves you of your irresponsible, misspelled, non-existent, quoted, and perfunctory jab with the use of "-phile" as your introductory word.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63608/discussion-between-andyt-and-ace).